# How to get a C++ program built in Visual Studio Code to accept user input

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm familiar with the Visual Studio IDE on Windows, and I wanted to give VSCode a shot. For my current situation, I am running VSCode on Ubuntu 64-bit. I installed VSCode, and then installed the C/C++ Extension. Next, I wrote a very simple C++ program that outputs "Hello World", and then asks the user to input their name. The program would then say/output hello to that user. Here's the issue: I am having trouble figuring out how to actually provide the user input to the program. During runtime, I see the cursor blinking in the output panel after the "Hello World" output, but when I press any keys on my keyboard to provide user input, nothing appears, and nothing happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string name = "";
    cout << "HELLO WORLD" << endl << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello " << name;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just because the cursor is blinking does not mean that your program is waiting for user input. Btw the C++ language does not care what IDE you use to write your code. Concerning your question: It is not clear what you are asking. If you need help with some code then please show the code (see also [mcve])

Comment: "when I press any keys on my keyboard to provide user input" ... do you also press enter ?

Comment: Working fine when running this program from terminal - but you better add '\n' to your output

Comment: @tobi303 of course i pressed enter. still nothing.

Comment: the console stays open, you still see "HELLO WORLD", the text you typed and a blinking cursor?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky when you say "run the program from the terminal", how exactly did you do that? and where exactly should I add "\n" to my output?

Comment: cout << "Hello " << name << '\n'; in Visual Studio Code   You have tabs below code window - PROBLEMS / OUTPUT / DEBUG CONSOLE / TERMINAL. Switch to terminal and run your program as ./<program name>. Or just open terminal and cd to your working dir and do the same

Comment: @tobi303 I am executing everything within VSCode. After I've saved my edits, I click on the run button at the top right of the screen (it looks like a "play" button). The VSCode output panel pops up on the bottom of the screen. On the "Output" tab is where I see "HELLO WORLD" and the blinking cursor right below it. Here is where anything I type does not show up. I then thought that maybe I needed to provide input on the "Terminal" tab to the right, but when I type a name and press enter, all I get is the standard shell error "command not found".

Comment: @duck_duck_goose Set a breakpoint at the return statement and put `endl` here `cout << "Hello " << name << endl; `

Comment: sry, I dont know VSCode, but use an ordinary command line window you can browse to the folder where VSCode placed the executable and run it from there. In any case the problem is something related to the console you are using and not about the [code which is working fine everywhere else](https://ideone.com/dZhRRM)

Comment: thanks everyone for your input!  @ArtemyVysotsky provided me the working solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better use terminal then the Visual Studio Code Run feature

[image: Better use terminal then the Visual Studio Code Run feature]

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  THANK YOU!!!  THANK YOU!!!  this method DEFINITELY works. MUCH APPRECIATED!!!