# Out/Input screen for Visual studio Code in C++ (on Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code for the first time for programming C++ in a Linux (gnome) environment. 
I have made a dummy .cpp file which asks me for an input value and then returns it in a string on the screen

However in Visual studio code I do not get an input or output screen. 
I have tried in my tasks.json file to add "presentation" "reveal": "always"

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g", "helloworld.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I didn't really find any answers that could help me anywhere. There was a "terminal": "integrated" attribute, but this one is deprecated.

Comment: Wow, you are a glutten for punishment. VS code on gnome? *gedit* or even [*geany*](https://github.com/geany/geany/) not up to your liking? Regardless, you are most likely being outsmarted by VSCode and the compiler and linker options. For anyone starting C++, use the command line so you understand the needed compiler options, then you can tell an IDE which to use. Open `gterminal` (or whatever gnome terminal is called now). `cd` to the dir containing your file, then `g++ -Wall -Wextra -o yourexename yourexesource.cpp` and let us know what the warnings are.

Comment: vs code has a terminal tab - use it to run your program https://stackoverflow.com/a/45944861/8491726